# What softwares are convenient to draw a quiver?

Tags: math-software, quiver

I would like to draw some quivers in a mathematical paper. What softwares are convenient to draw a quiver? Thank you very much.

Comment: Quiver?  You mean the thing people use to carry arrows? I think it would be better to use a photograph, rather than trying to draw one. If you must draw it, I would recommend Adobe Illustrator, or InkScape.

Comment: @bubba http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_(mathematics) ;)

Comment: Thank you. This confirms my suspicion that archery is a lot more fun than mathematics  :-)

Comment: maybe better suited for tex.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some prefer tikz or tikz-cd over xypic since it provides a bit more flexibility. A documentation of tikz-cd can e.g. be found [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you define convenient.

[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) has a command called quiver which is pretty good to plot vector fields/quiver.

If you need freeware, [Octave](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) has a quiver command as well.

I have not used it on [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/VectorVisualization.html) but it has many vectorplot functions. You might want to check documentation. If you do not have access to liscence, free version is available.

Answer (score 1):

For graphs and digraphs I use [xypic](https://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) in $\LaTeX$; it can do quivers too.  Very intuitive to use, just put the vertices in a coordinate axes and specify (directed) edges.